# How to get the occurence rate of the specific values with Apache Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the raw data DataFrame like that:

```
+-----------+--------------------+------+
|device     | timestamp          | value|
+-----------+--------------------+------+
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:01 |   100|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:02 |    99|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:03 |   100|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:04 |   102|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:05 |   100|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:06 |    99|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:11 |    98|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:12 |   100|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:13 |   100|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:15 |   101|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:17 |   101|
```

I'd like to aggregate them and to build the listed 10 s aggregation like that:

```
+-----------+--------------------+------------+-------+
|device     | windowtime         |      values| counts|
+-----------+--------------------+------------+-------+
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:00 |[99,100,102]|[1,3,1]|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:10 |[98,100,101]|[1,2,2]|
```

To plot a heat-map graph of the values later.

I have succeed with getting the `values` column but not clear how to calculate the corresponding `counts`

```
.withColumn("values",collect_list(col("value")).over(Window.partitionBy($"device").orderBy($"timestamp".desc)))
```

How can I do the weighted list aggregation in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by time window using [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function with duration of `10 seconds` to get counts by value and device, then group by `device` + `window_time` and collect list of structs:

```
val result = (
  df.groupBy(
    $"device",
    window($"timestamp", "10 second")("start").as("window_time"),
    $"value"
  )
  .count()
  .groupBy("device", "window_time")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"value", $"count")).as("values"))
  .withColumn("count", col("values.count"))
  .withColumn("values", col("values.value"))
)

result.show()
//+--------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
//|  device|        window_time|        values|    count|
//+--------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
//|device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:00|[102, 99, 100]|[1, 2, 3]|
//|device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:10|[100, 101, 98]|[2, 2, 1]|
//+--------+-------------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Great answer, I had no idea that `collect_list90` is applicable to a `struct()`