# How to export Spark DataFrame with columns having valuse lists aggregated with collect_list() to 3 dimentional Pandas in Pyspark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bokeh

I have the DataFrame like this one ([How to get the occurence rate of the specific values with Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893735/how-to-get-the-occurence-rate-of-the-specific-values-with-apache-spark))

```
+-----------+--------------------+------------+-------+
|device     | windowtime         |      values| counts|
+-----------+--------------------+------------+-------+
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:00 |[99,100,102]|[1,3,1]|
|   device_A|2022-01-01 18:00:10 |[98,100,101]|[1,2,2]|
```

`Windowtime` is considered to be X axis value, `values` are considered to be Y value, while `counts` are Z axis value (to be later plot say on heatmap).

How to export that to Pandas 3d object from PySpark dataframe?

With "2 dimensions", I have

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
```

and then I can use that for Bokeh's figure like that:

```
fig1ADB = figure(title="My 2 graph",  tooltips=TOOLTIPS, x_axis_type='datetime')
    fig1ADB.line(x='windowtime', y='values', source=source, color="orange")
```

But I'd like to use something like this:

```
hm = HeatMap(data, x='windowtime', y='values', values='counts', title='My heatmap (3d) graph', stat=None)
show(hm)
```

WHat kind of transformation I should do for that?

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by "Pandas 3d object"?   it is different from Pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Emma I have updated the question. I'm not a Python dev, I use Pandas only because I can't use Bokeh with Scala, so I don't know, what should be pandas dataframe to be acceptable by Bokeh to plot a heatmap

Comment: I see.  I think this question is about how you can plot PySpark/Pandas dataframe in Bokeh.  You should update the question and add Bokeh as a tag and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized, that the approach itself is wrong, there should be no aggregation to list done before the exporting to Pandas!

According to discussion below

https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/cant-render-heatmap-data-for-apache-zeppelins-pyspark-dataframe/8844/8

instead of grouped to list columns values/counts we have raw table with one line per unique id ('value') and value of count ('index') and each line has its 'write_time'

```
+-------------------+------+-----+
|window_time        |values|index|
+-------------------+------+-----+
|2022-01-24 18:00:00|999   |2    |
|2022-01-24 19:00:00|999   |1    |
|2022-01-24 20:00:00|999   |3    |
|2022-01-24 21:00:00|999   |4    |
|2022-01-24 22:00:00|999   |5    |
|2022-01-24 18:00:00|998   |4    |
|2022-01-24 19:00:00|998   |5    |
|2022-01-24 20:00:00|998   |3    |


rowIDs = pdf['values']
colIDs = pdf['window_time']

A = pdf.pivot_table('index', 'values', 'window_time', fill_value=0)

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x':[pd.to_datetime('Jan 24 2022')] #left most
                           ,'y':[0] #bottom most 
                           ,'dw':[pdf['window_time'].max()-pdf['window_time'].min()] #TOTAL width of image
                           #,'dh':[df['delayWindowEnd'].max()] #TOTAL height of image
                           ,'dh':[1000] #TOTAL height of image
                           ,'im':[A.to_numpy()] #2D array using to_numpy() method on pivotted df
                           })


color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=1, high=20)

plot = figure(toolbar_location=None,x_axis_type='datetime')
plot.image(x='x', y='y', source=source, image='im',dw='dw',dh='dh',  color_mapper=color_mapper)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=12)

plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

#show(plot)
show(gridplot([plot], ncols=1, plot_width=1000, plot_height=400))
```

And the result:

[image]